# PHP 4 level multidimensional associative array search

Tags: php, arrays

hi guys i have a multidimensional associative array and i want to search in the array.

```
public static function userAccessArray()
{
    return array(
        array(
            'title' => 'General',
            'access' => array(
                array('header' => 'Configuration' ,'link' => 'configuration', 'id' => 'configuration'),
                array('header' => 'Colleges'      ,'link' => 'college', 'id' => 'college'),
                array('header' => 'Periods'       ,'link' => 'period', 'id' => 'period'),
                array('header' => 'School'        ,'link' => 'school', 'id' => 'school'),
                array('header' => 'User Accounts' ,'link' => 'user', 'id' => 'user'),
                array('header' => 'Audit Log'     ,'link' => 'configuration/auditlog', 'id' => 'auditlog')
                )
        ),

        array(
            'title' => 'Offerings',
            'access' => array(
                array('header' => 'Programs'    ,'link' => 'program', 'id' => 'program'),
                array('header' => 'Departments' ,'link' => 'department', 'id' => 'department'),
                array('header' => 'Curriculum'  ,'link' => 'curriculum', 'id' => 'curriculum'),
                array('header' => 'Instructors' ,'link' => 'instructor', 'id' => 'instructor'),
                array('header' => 'Rooms'       ,'link' => 'room', 'id' => 'room'),
                array('header' => 'Sections'    ,'link' => 'section', 'id' => 'section'),
                array('header' => 'Subjects'    ,'link' => 'subject', 'id' => 'subject')
            )
        )
```

)
)

i want to search in LINK column if it exists i want to return the TITLE and the rest of access values in the array.

```
public static function searchUSerAccess($array, $val, $column)
{
    $arr = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value['access'] as $k => $v) {
            $keyres = array_search($val, array_column($v, $column));
        }
    }
}
 return Helpers::searchUSerAccess(Helpers::userAccessArray(), 'college', 'link');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `array_search()` isn't really suitable for your use case since according to [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php), it

> Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

`array_search()` is used more for a list of values discreet values in an array but we are interested in the value for a particular key that we know about, so this would not give back any interesting information. Instead we can iterate over the array and sub-arrays and check for equalities:

```php
public static function searchUSerAccess($array, $val, $column)
{
    // Loop through the top level array.
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        // Each iteration gives us
        // $value = array('title' => '…', 'access' => array(…))

        // Go through the 'access' element arrays, for a particular column
        // and value.
        foreach ($value['access'] as $access) {
            // Each iteration gives us
            // $access = array('header' => '…', 'link' => '…', 'id' => '…')
            
            // Check the value of the column we are interested in.
            if ($access[$column] === $val) {
                // If found, give back a merge of array members we
                // are interested in.
                return [
                    'title' => $value['title'],
                    ...$access,
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would give the following for your example:

```php
var_dump(Helpers::searchUSerAccess(Helpers::userAccessArray(), 'college', 'link'));
// array(4) {
//   ["title"]=>
//   string(7) "General"
//   ["header"]=>
//   string(8) "Colleges"
//   ["link"]=>
//   string(7) "college"
//   ["id"]=>
//   string(7) "college"
// }
```